# android steganography

Tags: android, steganography

I'm trying to implement steganography on Android...but the bitmap gets compressed when it's stored, and that changes the pixel values.  Is there any other way to store the image?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [android steganography](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644683/android-steganography)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of your newer question, because you provided more details there.  Don't re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a lossless compression method for your application since common compression methods with losses such as JPG will ruin your watermark data as you have checked. Taking a look at [Bitmap Compression formats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html) it seems that only JPG and PNG compression formats are available. AFAIK [png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) 
is a lossless compression method so you could use it to save your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

Try passing 100 as maximum value of compress quality, in this way you will compress the bmp loosless.

Comment: i tried with bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); but pix[0] value of image before compression and after compression is different so im unable to extract original data

Comment: You can take a look at this - http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/ This is some library for encoding/decoding images into a byte streams(and then you can save the bytestream to the SD card).