# android steganography

Tags: android, steganography

I'm doing steganography on Android.  My code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.src);
    picw = mBitmap.getWidth();
    pich = mBitmap.getHeight();
    pix= new int[picw * pich];
    mBitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);


try {               
       FileOutputStream fos = super.openFileOutput("dest.png", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
       fos.flush();            
       fos.close();            


    }catch (Exception e) {       
      tv.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
```

My problem is that whenever I save source image with the `Bitmap.compress()` method, the `pix[0]` value changes during compression, so I'm unable to extract original data.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your bitmap 24-bit or 32-bit? Does it change color format during compression? What is the value before and after? each element in Bitmap.getPixels() is a packed int representing a Color.

Comment: my bitmap is 32bit value of pix[0] before compression is:101111111011101110111101111010001 after compression 110010111001101110110100011010001 i dont want to change this pixel value as i want to hide data within it plz give suggestion..

Comment: What's the value of `mBitmap.getConfig()`?

Comment: value of mBitmap.getconfig is :ARGB_8888

Answer (score 0):

This is because of alpha premultiplication that android phones are using to get better performance with PNG images.
I was trying a few months ago to create a workaround but unsuccessfully.
As far as I know there is no solution for this type of steganography on android so far.

If you want to create better and more robust steganography for android use JPEG images with combination of libjpeg library and NDK. Also there is libraries for using wavelet in images which works too.