# steganography on android

Tags: android, steganography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android steganography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639430/android-steganography)

Has anyone implemented steganography on android?

Can anyone post sample code for it?

Comment: -1, Nothing to do with Android. Try Wikipedia or Google.

Comment: yup nothing 2 do with android. you have complete java api in android. so google it and youwould get sufficient material .infact in my own blog i added a small code snippet for steganography                    http://tech-villa.blogspot.com/2009/11/normal-0-false-false-false.html    http://tech-villa.blogspot.com/

Comment: but javax.Imageio api doesnt support in android which java api is used??

Comment: The very basis of the question makes it about Android, the user wanted to know how to implement Steganography on Android - the fact Steganography isn't specific to Android is a different matter.

Comment: This is now the third time you have asked this question within 24 hours. Please use other resources for your support needs, if you are not going to use StackOverflow properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an app called **[MobiStego](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobistego/)** which uses Steganography, it is open source, take a look through the files on the SVN at: [mobistego.svn.sourceforge.net](http://mobistego.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mobistego/MobiStegoAndorid/) they should be able to help you out.

Comment: thus this MobiStego can decrypt after encrypting the text into image?

Comment: @schadi, yes MobiStego appears to encrypt and decrypt images.

Comment: i have installed the mobiestego on my android device and it turns out that the encrypted image save as a PNG file. But the PNG files are not supported on sending it as mms.. My question is, can I change the format to JPEG?

Comment: @schadi I am not too sure if that is possible - the software is not mine, but it is open source so maybe you could look to see if there is a way to change the encoding when it saves the image.

Comment: @schadi: NO. because JPEG is a lossy compression image format. It works by REMOVING some information from the image, each time it's saved. So, you add some information (in terms of slight variations of a color component), and it removes or changes it. Unless you don't hide the information in the "tag area". But this is very easy to read (it's almost "in plain sight"), so it wouldn't be a clever thing to do.

Comment: I used this code but It turns out that image loses data when shared, copied or pasted.